# Modifying the pointee value in a const method

Tags: c++, constants

Look at this very simple piece of code:

```
struct A { char* s; };

class B
{
    A* a;

    public: B(const char* s) : a(new A()) {
        int len = strlen(s);
        a->s = new char[len + 1];
        memcpy(a->s, s, len + 1);
    }

    ~B() { delete [] a->s; delete a; }

    const char* c_str() const { return a->s; }

    const B& to_upper() const {
        char* x = a->s;
        int len = strlen(x);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            char k = x[i];
            if (k >= 'a' && k <= 'z')
                x[i] -= 32;
        }
        a->say_hi();
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    B b = "hola mundo";
    printf("%s\n", b.to_upper().c_str());
}
```

It works!! My question is... why?

The to_upper() method is const and modifies the value pointee by "a". Ok, I am not able to do something like "a = nullptr;" because the compiler says: "You are trying to modify a read-only object"; but it lets me modifying the underlying values. Is this behavior correct? Shouldn't the "a" type be converted to "const A*" in the same way that the type of "this" is converted to "const B*" in the const method?

Thanks!

Comment: You are using wrong delete[] in the dector of `B`.

Comment: nop, it is correct; I created a char array.

Comment: You aren't modifying the `B` object. You made no promises not to modify some other object (The thing pointed to by `a`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this const member function allow a member variable to be modified?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293857/why-does-this-const-member-function-allow-a-member-variable-to-be-modified)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constness of a method translates to the constness of the `*this` object, meaning that inside `to_upper` the `this` pointer has type `const B *`. That's all there is to it. No more, no less. The effect of this is not different from what you would see in C language, for example. It makes pointer `this->a` const, but it doesn't affect the pointee.

In fact it is up to you to decide whether the constness of `B` propagates to the `A` object pointed by `this->a`. The language gives you full freedom in making this decision. It is called "conceptual constness" (as opposed to "physical constness" or "logical constness"). The compiler observes and enforces only logical constness, while the purpose of keyword `const` in OOP goes far beyond that: it allows you to implement the idea of conceptual constness in your design.

If the `A` object is considered an integral part of `B`, then the constness of `B` should also mean constness of `A`. But this is something you have to observe and enforce manually (or some smart pointer class can help you with this).

If `A` object is an independent object which just happens to be merely *referenced* from `B`, then constness of `B` should not necessarily imply constness of `A`.

The compiler does not impose any decisions on you with respect to this, since compiler has no idea what object relationship you are trying to implement. In your design, the way I see it, the `A` object is actually an integral part of `B`, which means that you weren't supposed to declare your `to_upper` as `const`. It is a modifying function. It changes what is perceived by the user as the value of `B`. By declaring `to_upper` as `const` you are essentially "lying" to the user.

Comment: `The compiler observes and enforces only physical constness`, shouldn't that be `The compiler observes and enforces only logical constness`? Since physical constness AFAIK talks about putting the object in read-only memory which would be enforced at runtime.

Comment: @Jesse Good: I was using a slightly different terminology, but I agree that yours makes more sense. I modified the answer.

Answer (score 1):

const function must not modify class memebers. 'pointee by a' is not a member of the class.

Comment: The first sentence isn't completely correct, so this explanation fails.