# c_str implemenation for String class

Tags: c++, string, accelerated-c++

I am reading chapter 12 in the [Accelerated C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020170353X) book on implementing `string` class.

There is a end-of-chapter question to implement the `c_str()` function. I am looking for some ideas.

Here is what I have so far:

My first attempt was to *heap allocate* a `char *` and return it. But that would result in memory leaks:

```
cost char * c_star() const {
   //cannot get reference to result later
   //causes memory leaks

   char* result = new char[data.size() + 1];
   std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), result);
   result[data.size()] = '\0';
   return result;
}
```

Here is another attempt:

```
const char* c_str() const {
    //obviously incorrect implementation as it is not NUL('\0') terminated.
    return &data[0];
}
```

I cannot `push_back '\0'` to data since it should not change the data.

Here is the [spec](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/):

> Returns a pointer to an array that contains a null-terminated sequence of characters (i.e., a C-string) representing the current value of the string object.

Here is book implementation: (Renamed  to `Str`). Internally, the characters are stored in a vector implementation (Vec).

```
class Str {
    public:
       .
       .
       .

    private:
        Vec<char> data;
};
```

Comment: `return &data[0];` will work if you always allow enough space for the `'\0'` (and always have it there, or ensure it is added when necessary). Bear in mind that for C++11, it has to be an `O(1)` operation, so you pretty much have to do this. You *can't* allocate+copy, since that would be at least `O(n)`.

Comment: I liked your first solution. I'd go with it. :)

Comment: As @BoBTFish said, just always keep terminating 0 in object. it is required by C++11: `str[str.size()]` should return reference to symbol equal to `CharT()`, for string containing `char`s it is `'\0'`

Comment: so you mean to say whichever function is manipulating `data` field, has to make sure there is a `\0` in the end. In that case there should be a need for `data()` function correct?

Comment: @kmad179 That's one way, sure. Another way is to add the 0 terminator in the implementation of c_str(). You just need to ensure that you always allocate 1 byte more than needed whenever you grow the underlying storage. The need for data() is that it leaves it up to the implementation to chose how it solves this, so std::string isn't mandated to do it one way or another.

Comment: @nos in this case you would not be able to mark `c_str()` const, as it would change data member.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: Check out the C++ `mutable` keyword. Surprise! :-)

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Nothing stops an implementation from changing a an element in an underlying array even if c_str() is marked const. (you don't even need the mutable keyworkd to do that).

Comment: @ZanLynx sure, and for resource sharing there are global variables, right? Why spend time designing your program when a keyword or two slapped on it will fix immideate problem.

Comment: @nos, compiler usually does not like when you are trying to change underlying vector element in const functions.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: The mutable keyword's purpose is for exactly this situation. When the 0 is added to the string is purely an *internal* implementation detail. As long as the object *behaves* const externally then it *is* const.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot https://ideone.com/ufvuwW , this not even a warning. For c_str() of std::string it wouldn't break any semantics either, you've no business accessing up to `str.data() + str.length()`, so if a const method changed something you cannot observer, there's no harm There's several questions that states why this is fine, see e.g.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293857/why-does-this-const-member-function-allow-a-member-variable-to-be-modified

Comment: @nos OP code uses vector: https://ideone.com/xm9h7x

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Then don't use a vector if you want to go with that approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on the comments, I implemented the Str class be making sure there is a NUL('\0') at the end of every string. Instead of vector, I store data in a character array:

```
class Str {
    public:
        typedef char* iterator;
        typedef const char* const_iterator;
        .
        .
        .
        //c_str return a NUL terminated char array
        const char* c_str() const { return str_beg; };
        //c_str and data are same as implementation make sure there is NUL
        //at the end
        const char* data() const { return str_beg; };
        .
        .
        .

    private:
        iterator str_beg;
        .
        .
        .
};
```